# Variance of an estimator

Tags: variance, estimators

[image]

I have tried to proof the variance of this estimator.

Is this right?

[image]

Comment: This website supports math typesetting. Using math typesetting, instead of pasting images of Word documents, will make it easier to read your question and increase the likelihood of getting a useful answer. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You have to explain some notation for your post to be fully understood; e.g. what are $x_1,y_n,\ldots$.

Comment: It's not correct.  The duplicates give the formula to use.  BTW, there appears to be a typographical error in your expression for $\tilde \beta_1:$ the numerator likely involves only $x_1+x_n.$